# Namepaces gets added to the XML response after the conversion of the service from non-spring boot to spring boot

Tags: java, spring, soap, xml-namespaces, spring-ws

One of our service which works on SOAP protocol was converted from non-spring boot to spring boot microservice.

On the older code Axis OMElement was responsible to give the response. In Newer code we use spring webservices framework which explicitly return the object that spring marshals to a string.

Response snippet on the older version

```
    <ns2:foo xmlns:ns2="http://foo.bar/x" xmlns:ns3="http://foo.bar/y" xmlns:ns4="http://foo.bar/z">
<ns2:primaryKey>
<ns3:primaryKey>0af723ad3d989090a2fbf1c500000009</ns3:primaryKey>
</ns2:primaryKey>
</ns2:foo>
```

Response snippet on the newer version

```
    <ns2:foo xmlns:ns2="http://foo.bar/x" xmlns:ns3="http://foo.bar/y" xmlns:ns4="http://foo.bar/z">
<ns2:primaryKey>
<ns3:primaryKey xmlns:ns2="http://foo.bar/x" xmlns:ns3="http://foo.bar/y" xmlns:ns4="http://foo.bar/z">0af723ad3d989090a2fbf1c500000009</ns3:primaryKey>
</ns2:primaryKey>
</ns2:foo>
```

The above response is messy because we have unneeded namespace yet it is valid because the one that is needed is correct.

Sometimes on the newer version where we have as namespaces prefix which being associated with the wrong namespace as shown in the example below where ns3 prefix is reused.

```
    <ns2:foo xmlns:ns2="http://foo.bar/x" xmlns:ns3="http://foo.bar/y" xmlns:ns4="http://foo.bar/z">
<ns2:primaryKey>
<ns3:primaryKey xmlns:ns2="http://foo.bar/x" xmlns:ns3="http://foo.bar/z" xmlns:ns4="http://foo.bar/y">0af723ad3d989090a2fbf1c500000009</ns3:primaryKey>
</ns2:primaryKey>
</ns2:foo>
```

I am unaware why spring behaves in this way as I am new to it. Please let me what can be done to avoid this issue.

spring version: 2.7.18

Comment: Without a more realistic example, it's hard to understand whether there's an actual problem here. Reusing the same prefix with different meanings later in the document, while it's hard for a _human_ to read, should present no problem to a conformant XML parser. If you're saying that the wrong namespace is being assigned _to a particular element_, that's a different issue, and potentially unrelated to how many different `xmlns` attributes are in the file.

Comment: As for _why_ a serializer would work this way, my guess is that it's recursively serializing sections of the output in a "depth first" way - inner elements first, then wrapping them in the outer ones. So while it's serializing the "inside" elements, it doesn't know what prefixes will eventually end up declared at the top level, so just declares its own.